# How to pause a pylab figure until a key is pressed or mouse is clicked?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to program an animated simulation using pylab and networkx. The simulation is not interesting all the time so most of the time I want it to go fast, however, I want to be able to pause it and look at it when it looks interesting. Pausing the screen until keypress will solve my problem, because I can press the key as fast/slow as I want.

Here's an example situation:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt
import sys

def drawGraph(matrix):
    plt.clf()
    G = nx.DiGraph(np.array(matrix))
    nx.draw_networkx(G)
    plt.draw()

    plt.pause(1) #I want this pause to be replaced by a keypress
    #so that it pauses as long as I want

A=[[0,1],[1,0]]
B=[[0,1],[0,0]]
x=1
while True:
    if x==1:
        drawGraph(A)
        x=0
    else:
        drawGraph(B)
        x=1
```

How should I rewrite the plt.pause(1) line, so that the program pauses until keypress?

Some approaches suggested in other threads pauses the program, but the picture disappears or doesn't update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code stops and restarts with a *mouse click*. It uses the "TKAgg" backend:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

import pylab as plt
plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()

pause = False

def onclick(event):
    global pause
    pause = not pause

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

def drawGraph(matrix):
    fig.clear()
    G = nx.DiGraph(np.array(matrix))
    nx.draw_networkx(G)
    plt.draw()

A=[[0,1],[1,0]]
B=[[0,1],[0,0]]
x=1
while True:
    if not pause:
        if x==1:
            drawGraph(A)
            x=0
        else:
            drawGraph(B)
            x=1
    fig.canvas.get_tk_widget().update() # process events
```

Comment: +1 because this allows the user to not keep pressing on Enter in order to go through the drawings. This can be much more convenient.

Answer (score 61):

Is there some reason not to use waitforbuttonpress()?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A=[[0,1],[1,0]]
B=[[0,1],[0,0]]
x=1
while True:
    if x==1:
        drawGraph(A)
        x=0
    else:
        drawGraph(B)
        x=1
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

This will, as it says, wait for a key or button press for something to happen. It returns values if you want to know more about the event. Very easy.

Comment: `btnpress = plt.waitforbuttonpress(0.1)`
`if btnpress:`
`plt.waitforbuttonpress(-1)` This works for me. Quite good.

Answer (score 3):

plt.waitforbuttonpress() exits the inactive state as soon as either a key is pressed
or the Mouse is clicked. However, the function returns True if a keyboard key was pressed and False if a Mouse was clicked.

To hold plot until a keyboard key is pressed:

```
keyboardClick=False
while keyboardClick != True:
    keyboardClick=plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wait until the user presses enter with `raw_input()`.

In order for graphs to be displayed, `plt.ion()` should be added after the imports.

I don't think that there is any simple platform-independent way of waiting until a key is pressed in Python, but you might want to check this, if Enter is not enough.

Comment: This is the simple solution.. but it is also possible to do it with event handlers and `mpl_connect`

Comment: If I use `raw_input()` or something similar, the plot disappears. If I change `plt.draw()` to `plt.show()` the figure stops updating. So, this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: You need to do `plt.ion()` after `import … plt`. `ion()` is often a must, with Pylab/Pyplot. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `plt.pause(1)` in `drawGraph()` with `plt.ginput()`

Check [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.html).

*matplotlib.pyplot.ginput(n=1, timeout=30, show_clicks=True, mouse_add=<MouseButton.LEFT: 1>, mouse_pop=<MouseButton.RIGHT: 3>, mouse_stop=<MouseButton.MIDDLE: 2>)*

> Blocking call to interact with a figure.
>
> Wait until the user clicks *n* times on the figure, and return the
> coordinates of each click in a list.